# git-svn:update my local copy with changes in the 'trunk'

Tags: merge, git-svn

We have a git-svn repository.
I had no troubles to update the trunk with my local changes (commit + push or commit + merge), however sometimes my colleagues make some fixes in the code and update the git-svn and i want to take his changes without committing mine, since the code is not yet ready for commit (even locally, i might want to revert some of it). I can;t find a way to get his code and merge conflicting changes (i work with 'tower' git client on mac os x).

Any way to do the same action an svn 'update' command will do ?

10x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stash your current work in order to get a pristine working tree, allowing you to do your `git-svn update`.
You can see a similar technique in "[How to handle IDE project files with git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974371/how-to-handle-ide-project-files-with-git-svn)".

Another alternative is through [Stacked Git](http://www.procode.org/stgit/).
See "[How do I track local-only changes/change sets with git-svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636332/how-do-i-track-local-only-changes-change-sets-with-git-svn)".

> `StGit` is a Python application providing similar functionality to `Quilt` (i.e. pushing/popping patches to/from a stack) on top of Git.  *
>   These operations are performed using Git commands and the patches are stored as Git commit objects, allowing easy merging of the StGit patches into other repositories using standard Git functionality.

Comment: stashing the changes is the way to go for me, the merge if required later on is usually easy enough.
For mac i can recommend tower GUI tool for managing git repos, on windows i use the console, even eclipse is not good enough...